# MVC - change model's value in view on post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have view which displays some data from model. I have submit button which onClick event should change model's value and I pass model's with different values but my values in TextBoxFor stay the same as they were on page load. How can I change them?

Comment: Without any source code it's impossible to give any answers

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That's how HTML helpers work and it is by design. They will first look in the POSTed data and after that in the model. So for example if you have:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

which you are posting to the following action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SomeModel model)
{
    model.Name = "some new name";
    return View(model);
}
```

when the view is redisplayed the old value will be used. One possible workaround is to remove the value from the ModelState:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SomeModel model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("Name");
    model.Name = "some new name";
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Tried it in a very similar scenario.. doesn't seem to work. Any help will be appreciated here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138552/trying-to-update-the-model-in-controller-to-avoid-validation

Comment: Further to Darin's answer this works exactly the same with MVC4 and Razor.

Comment: This helped me so much, thank you! To the person who closed this question: you need to know what's being asked here before making your judgement whether this question is worth anything or not!!