# Values don't change after posting back to view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

*Edit: I've changed my question and code to clarify my question better*

I've got this (strongly typed view) that does use the values provided in the controller for that specific model

I want to add something to a Model from another model, after posting back from my httpPost action nothing happens...

Thanks in advance!

--------------------------------------other code to clarify my question a bit more----

```
 public class Address
 {
public int Id { get; set;}
public String Name { get; set;}
 }

 public class OtherAddress
 {
public int Id { get; set;}
public String Name { get; set;}
public String City { get; set;}
 }

 public class MasterModel
{
 public Address Address { get; set;}
 public List<OtherAddress> OtherAddressess { get; set;}
 }



 public ActionResult Create()
 {
 MasterModel Model = new MasterModel();
 Model.Person = new Person();
 Model.Address = new Address();
 Model.OtherAdressess = new List<OtherAddress>();

 DBContext _db = new DBContext();
 Model.OtherAdressess = _db.OtherAddressess.Where(a=> a.City == "Amsterdam");
 return View(Model);
 }
```

in the view

```
    @model Project.Models.MasterModel

    List<SelectListItems> items = new List<SelectListItems>();

    foreach(var a in Model.OtherAddressess)
    {
        SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
        item.Value = a.Id.toString();
        item.Text = a.Street;
    }

    @using (@Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <div>
    <select name="otheraddress">
    foreach(var i in Items)
    {
        <option value=@i.Value>@i.Text</option>
    }
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="select" value="Select Address"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Address.Name)
    <div>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
    }
```

in post

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MasterModel Model)
    {
    String otherAddressSelected = Request.Params["select"];
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(otherAddressSelected))
    {
        int id = int.Parse(Request.Params["otheraddress"]);
        DBContext _db = new DBContext();
        OtherAddress oa = _db.OtherAddress.Single(oa=> oa.Id == id);
        Model.Address.Name = oa.Name;
        return View(Model);
    }
    //other stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to change the value of your model in a [HttpPost] controller you have to remove the modelstate for the instance/attribute that you want to change. For example:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Index(SomeModel model)
  {
     ModelState.Remove("Name");
     model.Name = "some new name";
      return View(model);
  }
```

Got the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895691/mvc-change-models-value-in-view-on-post) example

Answer (score 0):

The input helpers in asp.net mvc will use the post values if they can find any before looking at the model.

In this situation here I think the problem is that you are trying to do more then one thing in the Create POST action. A action (as with any method in the application) should only do one thing. In your case I would do something like this (if I understand the work flow correctly that is):

```
//Action: SelectAddress
public ActionResult SelectAddress() {
    var addresses = _db.OtherAddressess.Where(a=> a.City == "Amsterdam");
    return View(new SelectAddressViewModel(addresses));
}

//View SelectAddress
....
<ul>
    @foreach(var address in Model.Addresses) {
        <li>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Product", new { addressId = address.Id })">
                @Model.Name
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
....

//Action Create
public ActionResult Create(int addressId) {
    var address = _db.OtherAddress.Single(oa=> oa.Id == addressId);
    var Model = new MasterModel();
    Model.Person = new Person();
    Model.Address = new Address {
                                    Name = address.Name
                                }

    return View(Model);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But isn't it a little weird that it doesnt even "see" my code in the action....? It's something like "Oh I already got something, i dont give a shit if you write in your controller-idea"..What can I do to have more influence in the way my controller reacts?

Comment: @Gyocol, To be honest I'm having trouble coming up with a situation where you wouldn't want this behavior really. If you post something and don't redirect the client to some other url, when would you want to display totally different data then what was posted? The reason it's there in the first place is so that you don't need to populate the whole model if you want to display the same view again after a post request (imo thats the right decision). I think that if this is a issue there is something wrong with the design. Maybe you should have redirected the user to another url?

Comment: Imagin you have another list of addressess that don't belong to a Person but you want to populate the Address for a person with some attributes of this other address to make the workflow for filling out data easier.

Comment: I don't think I understand your work flow I'm afraid. But when you have posted some data to the server, what you are supposed to see is the result of that post. There is a big difference between a HTTP GET and a HTTP POST. What you want to do here is probably to issue another GET (a redirect) to the same url before showing the form again.

Comment: Mattias, I'm sorry I guess I was too unclear about my question and code (i'll try to describe my problems better if I post more questions on the form). I've changed my code so that hopefully you can understand what I'm trying to do. Thank you for your time,

Comment: Now I _think_ see what you are trying to do. The problem here is that you are using your post action for more then one thing. It is there both to select a address to use as template and to create a new address. In my opinion that is the wrong design. I would probably add another action (with a corresponding view) before the create action where you'd select the address you'd like to copy information from. And then add the id of that address as a parameter to the GET action for Create.

Comment: Hi Mattias, thanks for the workaround. Your example has brought enough inspiration to create what I want. Thanks for your time! ps. I can't vote up cuz i'm new otherwise i would :)

Comment: No problems, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would create action method called details that would accept person id as parameter:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
   // Get person and display
}
```

Your Create action method is for creating Person type objects, and not displaying their details. So logically what you are doing doesn't seem right to me.

There should be action method to display view for creating a person and equivalent HTTP action method for persisting it into the database.

I would then re-direct to an action method for displaying Person type object information.

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = Person.Id });
```

Comment: thanks for your time but it's not to display info...it's to populate the model with attribute from other model before creating the model. See my comment to Mattias.