# ASP.NET MVC Stateless Nature

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, stateless

this is a conceptual question.

As far as I know, MVC has a stateless nature.
When I hit reload (F5) in my browser, the values I wrote or changed in the view, doesn't go away nor get replaced by the original values from the model.

Does anyone know why is this happening?
I'm assuming that in the moment I reload the page, the modified "not submitted" values should dissapear.

My views are only razor code... I'm not working with web forms (I mean, there are NO .aspx pages in my application)

---

```
@model PruebaMVC.Models.DatosLINQ.OPERACION

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Editar Operación</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Operación</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IDOperacion)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaOperacion, "Fecha de la Operación")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaOperacion)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaOperacion)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comision, "Comisión")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comision)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comision)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Legajo, "Número de Legajo")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Legajo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Legajo)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="formbutton" value="Guardar Cambios" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Volver al listado de Operaciones", "Index")
</div>
```

---

I hope not be inflicting any rule of the site by making a conceptual question. If I'm, please tell me, so I don't do this again.

Comment: Can you provide a simple code example?

Comment: Could you see the network traffic. Could be a case of browser caching

Comment: @neontapir: There's the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC HTML helpers will use the values posted to recreate the form.  If you want to ensure that your model's values get pushed to your view, remove them from the model state in your controller.

You can use either

```
public ActionResult MyController (MyModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ModelState.Clear ();
    }

    return View (model);
}
```

or you can remove specific items you want to update

```
public ActionResult MyController (MyModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ModelState.Remove ("PropertyNameToRemove");
    }

    return View (model);
}
```

I'm not sure where you're doing the updating (either manually in the controller, or in the model itself) but you just have to remove any or all of the items from ModelState and they will be repopulated.

[See this question, as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895691/mvc-change-models-value-in-view-on-post).

Comment: But the thing is that I'm not submiting the page, I'm never reaching the "POST" ActionResult.

Either way, now I understand what are you saying, it's been really helpful that link.

If ASP.NET MVC implements those HTML Helpers, where's the stateless nature that they so much talk about?

Comment: Are you loading the page, submitting, and hitting F5?

Comment: But also, if I remove the value from the model state (I think, this should be done in the "GET" ActionResult where the model is passed to the View()) how is the original value gonna be shown in the view?

Comment: Nope, I'm loading, changing values (just in the view), NOT submitting, and reloading.
The values should go back to its original unmodified state, or am I wrong?

Comment: Firstly, if you're submitting your form, and then hitting F5, depending on your browser, it is just going to refresh your current screen--meaning you will see everything that you had after you got the page back.  This is *NOT* performing a HTTPGET.  Secondly, when you remove the property or properties from ModelState, it is not removing it from your model.  It is removing it fromt he POSTed values.

Comment: You are correct, if you are not submitting the form, the values *should* go back to the original state.