# Trying to update the model in controller to avoid validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following property in my model:

```
[Display(Name = "ActivityModel_FlashFile", ResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Models))]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ActivityModel_FlashFile_Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Models))]
public string FlashFile { get; set; }
```

And in my controller I do:

```
 ModelState.Remove("FlashFile");
 model.FlashFile = "1";
 try
 {
    this.UpdateModel(model);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    string allErrors=string.Join(",",ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(e=>e.ErrorMessage));
 ...
```

(FlashFile is empty when we get to the beginning of this snippet).
And yet, at this point `allErrors` is "Flash file is required".

(I took the idea of doing it like that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895691/mvc-change-models-value-in-view-on-post)).

How can I avoid validating the FlashFile property?

Comment: Why don't you just take the Required off the FlashFile property?

Comment: I need it in some cases (originally I assign FlashFile an "artificial" value in an IF statement, but I simplified that for the question). I also need it for client side validation

Comment: if you need it some cases, then your situation is best suited to the ViewModel pattern (see more here: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/model-view-viewmodel-design)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I avoid validating the FlashFile property?

By using a view model that is adapted to the requirements of this view. That's the proper way to do it. If the `FlashFile` property is not required then design a view model which doesn't have the `Required` attribute on it for this action.

The wrong way to approach this is to attempt to reuse your domain models and then exclude the properties that you don't want from model binding:

```
try
{
    this.UpdateModel(model, null, null, new[] { "FlashFile" });
    model.FlashFile = "1";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string allErrors = string.Join(
        ",", 
        ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)
    );
    ...
}
```

Comment: Amazingly enough, this gives the exact same error. I have no idea how that's possible.... (and as for creating a new model - the validation is dependent upon user's selection which (currently) doesn't involve server side sending a new view or anything of that sort).