# Change model property in post request asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have one problem.

This is short example.
This is model.

```
    public class MyModel
    {
         string Title{get;set;}
    }
```

In view I write

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title)
```

This is controller.

```
    public ActionResult EditNews(int id)
    {
        var model = new MyModel;
        MyModel.Title = "SomeTitle"

        return View("News/Edit", model);
    }
    //for post
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditNews(MyModel model)
    {
        //There is  problem.When I do postback and
        // change Title in this place,Title  doesn't change in view textbox
        //Only when I reload page it change.
        model.Title = "NEWTITLE"

        return View("News/Edit", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It won't change because by default (many think this is a bug) MVC will **ignore** the changes you make to the model in a `HttpPost` when you're returning the same View. Instead, it looks in the `ModelState` for the value that was originally served to the view.

In order to prevent this, you need to clear the `ModelState`, which you can do at the top of your `HttpPost` by doing:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

Comment: Also, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4896336/1869660
If you don't want to clear the whole `ModelState`, you can call `ModelState.Remove("Title")` instead.

Comment: So it was an intentional bug.